# Is the new chromedriver version 113 unoffuscable?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

For a scraping project, I use java and Selenium with chromedriver to interact with Indeed. I use several "classic" method, and I obfuscate the chromedriver exe to avoid giving the same browser signature (see this article to see the whole process: https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html)

But lately, I updated my chrome browser to the 113 version, so I tried to download and obfuscate the new chromedriver version 113. I opened the exe with notepad, but I'm enable to find the function getPageCache, and therefore could not change the browser signature.

This is a big issue for me, since the app is supposed to be on user computer, where I cannot control their chrome version. And, since I get caught by cloudflare.

Chromedriver vers 112
[image]

Chromedriver vers 113
[image]